# How to validate a Long.parselong passwd try catch

Tags: java

here is my situation.  I have a project that I am doing.  I'm using netbeans 8.0.2 IDE java language.  Here is my code:

```
try{
    memdt = request.getParameter("member date");
    if(!memdt.isEmpty()){
        n.setMemdt(memdt);
    }else{
        msg += "Member date field is empty<br>";
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    msg += "Member date error: " + e.getMessage() + "<br>";
}
```

That code is fine but what I want to do now is validate using the try catch method for password and that is a long character.  Does anyone know how to do that?  Thank you.

Comment: Did not understand the question, sorry.

Comment: I'm trying to use try catch method to validate a long.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: A long what?  And what do passwords have to do with this?  The IDE is generally irrelevant for programming questions, but the java version may be useful.  Does this code form part of a servlet (I only suggest this because of the use of a `request` property)?

Comment: Password is the name of the long property.  and yes you are correct it is for a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the title of your question, you are trying to do something like this:

```
try {
    Long.parseLong(memdt);
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    msg += "Member date error: not a number";
}
```

`NumberFormatException` it's what the `Number` classes generally throw when a string can not be parsed. The result of `Long.parseLong()` is discarded since the `long` value it returns is irrelevant, the test just checks that the parsing can be done.